# How to get div to compress dynamically with viewport height?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I have been searching for an answer to what I feel is a fairly basic question, but I can not figure out what is wrong about code. I have a project using the bootstrap library with php and the goal is to fit all the content on the page within the viewport, and I was hoping someone could help me about the solution or any advice on what I am doing wrong. The code included is the gallery section and while it compresses horizontally I also need it to compress vertically.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
        <img src="images/test1.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
        <img src="images/test1.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
        <img src="images/test1.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 gallery">
          <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
            <img src="images/test1.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 gallery">
          <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
            <img src="images/test1.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 gallery">
          <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
            <img src="images/test1.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- personal CSS -->
<style>

.wrapper{
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

.gallery {
background-color: #000000;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
  }

.gallery:hover {
z-index: 2;
}

.gallery img:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 48px 22px rgba(222,222,222,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 48px 22px rgba(222,222,222,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 48px 22px rgba(222,222,222,1);
transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
opacity: 1;
}

.gallery img {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: .5;
}

div.desc {
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example on Fiddle or Codepen?

With what you have provided, I've come up with this Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sebdum/wctffuh3/1/

It's pretty simple:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100wh;
}

.div {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  height: 33vh;
}
```

But you need to be aware of smaller devices such as iPhone 5 which has effective vertical resolution of 568px, which would make each div rather small. Also somewhat obviously, this works only with known number of elements, as dynamic implementation looks for a more complex solution, possibly involving JS.

Comment: I will be adding a separate exception for xs screens, but after I'm able to implement this, and in the case of this issue there will always be six items

Comment: If you need only six items you can use 33.33% width on each div and 50vh height for two rows. If you found these examples helpful please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yea I have tried this approach and it works for the resizing, the problem I run into is that in order to get them lined up horizontally across the screen i need to float them (float: left) and when you float elements z-index does not apply so when the images increase in size on hover any element above it on the stack will overlap. Any advice?

Comment: Got it to work. Solution was to keep the bootstrap format while implementing what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @MattMorgan Glad to help. Remember to upvote, thanks!